# HD2 crashing on VirtualBox USB

Tags: usb-debugging, htc-hd2

I have an HD2 mounting AmeriCan Android on SDCard. When I mounted it as USB device on a Windows Virtual PC machine, it worked fine.

I recreated my dev environment from scratch into VirtualBox but now when I connect the phone to VirtualBox Android crashes and WinMo reboots back.

Can somebody help me? Thanks

Comment: When exactly does it crash?  Only if VirtualBox is running?

Comment: Question edited. I forgot to say that it happens when I mount the device in the VirtualBox machine via menu. Exactly as I did with with WVPC USB menu on top bar